# Not able to export variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Using mocha trying to export variable from testHook file but getting undefined in test file, my code is ::

Test File :

```
 var xyz = require("testHook").xyz;

 class test1 {
 execute() {
  describe("test suite 1", async () => {
    it("test 1", async () => {
      console.log(xyz);
    });
    });
  }
}
new test1().execute();
```

testHook.js

```
 function abc()
 {
 //do some stuff and assume value to be returned is 10 
 exports.xyz = 10;;
 }
 beforeEach(() => {
  abc();
  console.log(this.xyz);
 });
```

Output ::

```
 test suite 1
 10
 undefined
 ✓ test 1: 1ms
 Suite duration: 0.009 s, Tests: 1
 1 passing (10ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should import TestHook;

```
var testHook = require("testHook");

class test1 {
 execute() {
   describe("test suite 1", async () => {
     it("test 1", async () => {
       console.log(testHook.xyz);
     });
   });
 }
}
new test1().execute();
```

By the time xyz is imported, the test has not begun yet, therefore the beforeEach is not called yet. So, the imported xyz is the copy of the original variable before being set.